# SMS Gateway for SMS Notifications with Worklight using HTTP POST?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM Worklight Studio V6.2.0.0 and I would like to use Worklight SMS Notification messages with Skebby SMS Broker. I configured the `SMSConfig.xml` file as well for the Broker according to [Worklight documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fadmin%2Fr_sms_gateway_config.html) and [Skebby documentation API](http://www.skebby.com/business/index/send-docs/#sendSMSClassicMethodSection) :

```
<sms:config xmlns:sms="http://www.worklight.com/sms/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <gateway id="skebby" hostname="gateway.skebby.it" port="80" 
            programName="api/send/smseasy/advanced/http.php" toParamName="recipients[]" textParamName="text">
        <parameter encode="true" name="method" value="send_sms_classic"/>
        <parameter encode="true" name="username" value="foo"/>
        <parameter encode="true" name="password" value="foo"/>
        <parameter encode="true" name="sender_string" value="Foo"/> 
    </gateway>
</sms:config>
```

From WebSphere Console output, I don't see any error but analyzing HTTP traffic, I see an error since the request is made by HTTP GET and this method but only POST is allowed.

How can I "force" HTTP POST instead of GET?

Then I tried to use HTTPS using port 443 with no luck getting a ClientProtocolException, is it possible to use HTTPS?

Then I've figured out that the value `recipients[]` of the `toParamName` key is urlencoded `recipients%5B%5D=`, how to avoid also this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the SMS support in Worklight supports only `HTTP` and only `GET` calls.

You can submit a feature request to be evaluated by Worklight product designers for future releases.
See here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Comment: I still cannot use it even with GET due the auto encoding of the `toParanName` recipients[] field in `recipients%5B%5D=` , how to avoid this? Is it possible to pass recipient number by a custom param using some placeholder in order to identify the phone number?

Comment: Feel free to open a PMR and have the development team look more closely at your issue.

Comment: Hi, I could successfully setup a configuration for Skebby as SMS Aggregator for IBM Worklight V6.2 using a GET API with other params. Here the SMSConfig.xml: https://github.com/blues-man/worklight-skebby-smsnotifications/blob/master/server/conf/SMSConfig.xml hope it helps enhance Worklight SMS push notifications offer